# How to remove numeric values but keep alphanumeric values

Tags: python

`words = ["my name is john123. I am 23 years old."]`

**expected output** -:
`my name is john123. I am years old.`

How can I get this output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regular expression.

```
import re

st = ''.join(words)
reg = re.compile(r'\b\d+\b\s*')
res = reg.sub('', st)
```

Here `\b` is for word boundary, `\d+` matches one or more digits and end `\s*` matches zero or more white space at the end of your numeric word. You can remove `\s*` depending on your requirement.

More info abount [Python regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
words = ["my name is john123. I am 23 years old."]
words = [x for x in words[0].split() if not x.isdigit()]
print(words)
```

Try this.